# How can the memoize cache be cleared?

Tags: python, unit-testing, caching

I use the following decorator to cache pure function returns:

```
def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer
```

It works quite well, but I am running into a problem with unit tests such as this:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # clear the cache here
        pass

    @patch('module1.method1')
    def test_method1_1(self, method1):
        method1.return_value = ""
        d = module1.method2()
        self.assertTrue(len(d) == 0)

    @patch('module1.method1')
    def test_method1_2(self, method1):
        method1.return_value = "TEST1234"
        d = module1.method2()
        self.assertTrue(len(d) == 2)
```

My problem is that `module1.method1` is decorated with `memoize`, and so from one test to the other, its return value is cached and is not changed with subsequent `method1.return_value = "..."` assignments.

How can the memoize cache be cleared? When I figure this out I would clear the cache in the setUp method of the test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator works by injecting a dictionnary in the function

You can manually clear that dictionnary:

```
@memoize
def square (x):
  return x*x

square(2)
square(3)

print square.__dict__
# {'cache': {(2,): 4, (3,): 9}}

square.cache.clear()
print square.__dict__
# {'cache': {}}
```

You can use `module1.method1.cache.clear()` in your TearUp method

Answer (score 2):

Because from this accepted answer passed almost 6 years. For python 3.6 this works little different now:

```
In [26]: @memoize()
    ...: def save_random(x):
    ...:     return x * random.random()
    ...: 

In [27]: save_random(2)
Out[27]: 0.39443014715316504

In [28]: save_random(2)
Out[28]: 0.39443014715316504

In [29]: save_random(1)
Out[29]: 0.42043961241931294

In [30]: save_random(1)
Out[30]: 0.42043961241931294

In [31]: save_random.__dict__
Out[31]: 
{'__wrapped__': <function __main__.save_random(x)>,
 'uncached': <function __main__.save_random(x)>,
 'cache_timeout': <object at 0x7f0bf3f0a250>,
 'make_cache_key': <function memoize.Memoizer._memoize_make_cache_key.<locals>.make_cache_key(f, *args, **kwargs)>,
 'delete_memoized': <function memoize.Memoizer.memoize.<locals>.memoize.<locals>.<lambda>()>}

In [32]: save_random.delete_memoized()

In [33]: save_random(1)
Out[33]: 0.39032536564874865

In [34]: save_random(2)
Out[34]: 1.093048214445716
```

So to clear/delete memoize now we need to use `method1.delete_memoized`.